# JUnit best practices

Tags: java, junit, message-queue, amazon-sqs

I am writing an in-memory implementation of Queue Services (similar to Amazon SQS) for local  testing.

By specification, a pull() call on non-empty queue doesn't have to return a message. In case of just one consumer, my In-Memory implementation will always return a message. So, the first test case (correct in terms of SQS specification) is obviously useless and would pass even with an empty pull() implementation always returning null:

```
@Test
public void testPushAndPullBySpec() {//useless
    QueueService qs = new InMemoryQueueService();

    qs.push("TEST_MSG_1");

    Message message = qs.pull();
    Assert.assertTrue(message == null || message.getBody().equals("TEST_MSG_1"));
    if (message != null) {
        qs.delete(message.getReceiptHandle());
    }
}
```

This implementation looks meaningful, but it actually contradicts the specification and cannot be used with other implementations:

```
@Test
public void testPushAndPullByImpl() {
    QueueService qs = new InMemoryQueueService();//could fail if another implementation was used

    qs.push("TEST_MSG_1");

    Message message = qs.pull();
    Assert.assertTrue(message.getBody().equals("TEST_MSG_1"));
    qs.delete(message.getReceiptHandle());
}
```

So, my only question is: how do I write my unit tests correctly in this situation?

Comment: If your queue has a stricter contract than the spec, and should always return the first element when the queue isn't empty, then the test should check that contract. Not the contract in the specification.

Comment: Why write your own mock of SQS when you can just use [ElasticMQ](http://www.schibsted.pl/blog/mocking-amazon-sqs-with-elasticmq/)? It's already very well established and works great for local tests.